No redirect params in URI even though there is one - Facebook
I am trying to properly set up my Facebook login link, however, I have no idea what the login URL is actually supposed to be. The furthest I have gotten is that my app ID is formatted correctly, and that my response type is correct. Everything else I am unfamiliar with.
What my URL currently looks like: "https://www.facebook.com/v19.0/dialog/oauth?client_id=[my ID]&redirect_uri="https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html"&state="{st=[st],ds=[ds]}"&response_type=token"
I have tried removing square brackets (to get the above link), but that didn't work. It does not redirect to the redirect URI and instead pretends that I don't have such URI. I looked at similar posts about this error, however, in those posts, you often have to white list the link, attempting to white list my link results in Facebook that I cannot white list Facebook links.
Turning on "Embedded Browser OAuth Login" also does not solve the problem.

I fixed the problem. The solution is to remove the quotation marks surrounding the link.
